# MySQL load file not working as expected

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this data in my file (sometimes fields could be in double quotes) as shown below:

```
1, "ala",   johnes, 2017-09-01, 100
2, dqwdqdq,, 2017-09-01, 101
```

Data is loaded to database however quotes are also inserted into column so instead to see `ala` i see `"ala"` in the column.

My code:

```
    Using exclecon As New MySqlConnection("Server=Localhost;DataBase=mobily;user=root;password=897;")
        Dim uploadQry As String = "Load DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/test.csv' INTO TABLE Test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '""' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 0 LINES;"
        Dim myCUpload As New MySqlCommand(uploadQry, exclecon)
        exclecon.Open()
        myCUpload.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Comment: That's not a "problem", that's just the way your data is.

Comment: @Plutonix i tried with mysqlbulk approach diffrent ways however no one was working as epxected i decided try with this approach this time.

Comment: @Plutonix (probably i deleted your message by mistake. @I realized that when there are spaces between separator and value then quotes as traded as value - does it mean that correct csv format cannot have spaces between values and separators?